# spring data jpa throws exception and does not persist data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, eclipselink

I do have a Java Spring 4 application and I try to persist an entity. But instead I get an  exception:

```
Invalid property 'id' of bean class [my.backend.domain.SystemUser]: Getter for property 'id' threw exception.
```

The data are not being stored in the database. The general database setup works, I already use it for login.

I have service class calling the Spring Data JPA method:

```
public SystemUser create(SystemUser systemUser) {
    SystemUser newUser = systemUserRepository.saveAndFlush(systemUser);
    return newUser;
}
```

The debugger shows me the systemUser instance contains the following values:

```
systemUser = {my.backend.domain.SystemUser@20651}
address = {java.lang.String@20689}"asdf"
companyName = {java.lang.String@20688}"asdf"
costCenter = {java.lang.String@20697}"asdf"
customerNumber = {java.lang.String@20696}"asdf"
email = {java.lang.String@20695}"asdf@asdf.com“
fax = {java.lang.String@20694}"asdfadsf"
id = null
location = {java.lang.String@20691}"df"
password = null
phone = {java.lang.String@20693}"asdf"
primaryContact = {java.lang.String@20692}"fdfd"
roles = {java.util.ArrayList@20687} size = 2
userType = {my.backend.domain.UserType@20686}"CLIENT"
zipCode = {java.lang.String@20690}"asdf"
```

and this is my SystemUser entity (I use EclipseLink):

```
package my.backend.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "system_users")
public class SystemUser implements Serializable {

public static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "usertype")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private UserType userType;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "system_user_role",
        joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(
                        name = "system_user_id",
                        referencedColumnName = "id"
                )
        },
        inverseJoinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(
                        name = "role_id",
                        referencedColumnName = "id"
                )

)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();

@Column(name = "companyname")
private String companyName;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "zipcode")
private String zipCode;

@Column(name = "location")
private String location;

@Column(name = "primarycontact")
private String primaryContact;

@Column(name = "phone")
private String phone;

@Column(name = "fax")
private String fax;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "customernumber")
private String customerNumber;

@Column(name = "costcenter")
private String costCenter;

public SystemUser() {
}

public SystemUser(String username) {
}

/* getters and setters */

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public UserType getUserType() {
    return userType;
}

public void setUserType(UserType userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}

public List<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getPrimaryContact() {
    return primaryContact;
}

public void setPrimaryContact(String primaryContact) {
    this.primaryContact = primaryContact;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getFax() {
    return fax;
}

public void setFax(String fax) {
    this.fax = fax;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCustomerNumber() {
    return customerNumber;
}

public void setCustomerNumber(String customerNumber) {
    this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
}

public String getCostCenter() {
    return costCenter;
}

public void setCostCenter(String costCenter) {
    this.costCenter = costCenter;
}

}
```

Summary: Data are not persisted and saveAndFlush(systemUser) does not generate an ID, so it throws the exception mentioned above.

If I missed to provide any information, please let me know, and I will add it immediately.

============================
Thanks to vbera, I found a really embarrassing issue: the getter and setter of id had long instead of Long.

Now I do have an exception:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5):
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' 
for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
Call: INSERT INTO system_users (address, companyname, costcenter, customernumber, email, fax, 
location, password, phone, primarycontact, usertype, zipcode) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf, asdf@asdf.com, fsad, asdf, null, asfd, asf, CLIENT, asdf]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(my.backend.domain.SystemUser@2d787ac2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Getter-setter method for id should be :

```
public Long getId() { // Long instead of long
    return id;
} 

public void setId(Long id) { // Long instead of long
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: But that is not the issue. Even If the id is null it must be generated while saving.

Comment: Yes, id is generated while saving and setter method is used internally to save id in object. But it's not able to find proper setter method for id that's why it will throw an error. hope I'm clear

Comment: I corrected it and can confirm that this is not the issue.

Comment: Okay, new information: I corrected the getter, too and now I get a duplicate key error - I add this to my original question.

Comment: That's because you have duplicate id in your db

Comment: Yes, but why and how to fix it? I need to tell eclipselink to start the generation with the first unused id.

Comment: This solved my main issue so far, so I will mark this answer as correct. I am already three steps further. Thank You, vbera.

Comment: One solution is to remove the data from table and run the program again. and second solution is to use increment generator instead of identity

Answer (score -1):

Is it missing an annotation for Id?
Like :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
```

Comment: The name of the database column is id, so there is no need for further annotating the id property.